# Dev Ops is changing a variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a DevOps build script that looks like this:

```
variables:
  MyConnectionString: ''

stages:
  - stage: BuildApp
   . . .
   # build app
   . . .

    - job: RunApp
      steps:

      - script: |        
          echo ${{variables.MyConnectionString}}
```

The issue that I have is that the connection string is not coming through to the script - I've set it in the edit variables, but it comes through as blank.  I tried setting it directly in the script, but when I did that, it appeared to truncate the value at the semi-colon.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental around how these variables work.  Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are calling the variable is actually for pipeline parameters or varibles template expressions

Calling variables or group variables into tasks should be just using the [macro syntax interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables) `$(MyConnectionString)` syntax.

So change it to:

```sh
echo $(MyConnectionString)
```

Or use the other format of defining variables (usually used when you're also referring to variable groups)

```yaml
variables:
- group: myVarGroup
- name: MyConnectionString
  value: connectioncreds
```

And also make sure to check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) for more info about devops variables.

Comment: I tried your suggested, but the value is still empty

Comment: How is the structure of the connection string? Can you try to put a simple single string or number and see if it shows up?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that - whatever I put in there as a variable it just doesn't being through

Comment: Can you try the other format I posted in the answer? Also what about the BuildApp portion - do you have any script there that's also able/unable to call the pipeline variable?

Comment: Could you share an entire working version of your pipeline (removing any sensitive lines etc) that I can use to reproduce on my end? All tests I've done so far seem to be ok. It's possible there's something wrong with your yaml itself.

Comment: The new variable format that you've described works better: it does print the connection string, but there's an ampersand in the password, and it seems to split it on that.  However I need it to work based on the variables, as I obviously can't store a real connection string in source code.

Comment: If you put it in double quotes it still splits on it? Have you considered using a variable group (under devops library) with the connection string as a secret variable? Updated the answer to reflect var groups. Once you set the group, you can just call the variable the same way as if it was defined in the variables section

Comment: It's now got past splitting on the sem-colon, but there is a < (less than) symbol in the connection string, which it seems to be trying to perform a pipe operation with, so I get an error saying the file [text after the < symbol] doesn't exist